# How to make the row height of a grid taller

Tags: acumatica

How can I make the row height of a grid taller?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should try creating a custom CSS class for the row element.  You can add some runtime code to the .cs code file for the page.  See this [article](https://asiablog.acumatica.com/2016/12/using-colors-in-acumatica.html)